# Считывание строки с бинарного файла C++

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, binary

Есть класс Primitive, в нем есть 1 поле - str(строка). Я выделяю динамичский двумерный масив объектов класса - **arr**, заполняю его любыми данными(буквально по пару символов) и записываю это все в бинарный файл ( это все реализовано в **test.cpp** ). Далее, в **main.cpp** я создаю аналогичный динамический двумерный массив - **new_arr**, дальшее считываю данные с того же бинарного файла в этот массив, далее просто вывожу его. Проблема в том, что выводит пустые строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему

*ОС - linux*

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

class Primitive
{
    private:

    std::string str;

    public:

    Primitive()
    {
        str = ' ';
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Primitive& prim);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Primitive& prim);

};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Primitive& prim)
{
    in >> prim.str;

    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Primitive& prim)
{
    out << prim.str << std::endl;

    return out;
}   




static const int MAX_SIZE = 3;

void Task()
{
    Primitive** arr = new Primitive*[MAX_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new Primitive[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++)
        {
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }


    std::ofstream file("~/avept/oop/college_op/file.bin", std::ios::binary);
    file.write((char*)(&arr), sizeof(arr));
    file.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.cpp"

int main()
{
    Task();

    Primitive** new_arr = new Primitive*[MAX_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        new_arr[i] = new Primitive[MAX_SIZE];
    }

    std::ifstream file("~/avept/oop/college_op/file.bin", std::ios::binary);
    file.write((char*)(&arr), sizeof(arr));
    file.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++)
        {
            std::cout << new_arr[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        delete[] new_arr[i];
    }

    delete[] new_arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы в **main.cpp** даже не прикасаетесь к файлу и не считываете ничего.  А в **test.cpp** записываете всего восемь байт, так как это размер указателя `sizeof(arr) == 8`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ой, исправил считывание, Но все-равно таже ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а какой размер вместо размера указателя надо вписать?

Comment: надо не `write` использовать везде, а потоки : `file << str` запись, `file >> str` чтение

Comment: но мне же надо именно в бинарном виде, или при file << str тоже будет в бинарном? Также вопрос как считывание сделать, мы же длину строк из файла не знаем

Comment: Вы не знаете длину строки в файле и в потоковой записи будут удобнее. В бинарном режиме в конце строки будет лишний конец строки `'\n'`. Не помню точно, надо проверить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись в `Task()` :

```
...
std::ofstream file("file.bin", std::ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++)
    {
        std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        file  <<  arr[i][j];
    }
}

file.close();
...
```

Чтение в `main` :

```
...
std::ifstream file("file.bin", std::ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++)
    {
        file  >>  new_arr[i][j] ;
        // в строке уже есть '\n' не буду лишнее выводить
        std::cout << new_arr[i][j] /*<< std::endl*/;
    }
}

file.close();
...
```

Comment: больше спасибо!